# android set wallpaper as app background

Tags: android

I want that when a user clicks a button in an app, they get a dialog box that allows them to select a wallpaper from albums, a set of live wall papers, system wall papers or even images. I'd like the functionality to be exactly like it is with the home page wallpaper except that I need this selected image to be the background of my `Main Activity`. So, When they select it and click set as wallpaper, this image should be used as app's background drawable.

I have this for a start:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(
               WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
       intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP,
               new ComponentName(MainActivity.class),
                       Wallpaper.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

My second idea is to use set background bitmap using `WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setBitmap(bitmap);`
I don't know which direction to move..

Comment: And you have tried nothing so far in this direction? Do you have some code to share perhaps?

Comment: All right - made some more changes to your question to try to improve the readability.

Comment: One more suggestion would be try looking for a tutorial like this online --> http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/wallpaper-example-in-android-programming/. Maybe work through it - see what's going on.

Comment: You could take the launcher code and customize it, remove the HOME intent filter and check how they are showing the wallpaper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for getting the current system wallpaper:

Just get the drawable from WindowManager:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

An set it to a ImageView:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Comment: You didn't understand me really. I don't want to get the current system wallpaper. I want I want that when a user clicks a button in an app, they get a dialog box that allows them to select a wallpaper from albums, a set of live wall papers, system wall papers or even images. I'd like the functionality to be exactly like it is with the home page wallpaper except that I need this selected image to be the background of my Main Activity and not user's home page.Once selected, we should return with this wallpaper and set it as app background.